# Como usar Spread do ES6+ para fazer metamorfose de um objeto dentro de outro?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Tenho o seguinte objeto abaixo:

```
const usuario = {
      nome: 'Diego',
      idade: 23,
      endereco: {
        cidade: 'Rio do Sul',
        uf: 'SC',
        pais: 'Brasil',
      }
};
```

vou criar um `usuario2` com base no objeto `usuario` acima, porém, irei alterar o nome para Gabriel

```
const usuario2 = { ...usuario, nome: 'Gabriel' };
```

obtive sucesso.

Agora vou tentar criar um `usuario3`, porém alterando a cidade para Lontras.

```
const usuario3 = { ...usuario, endereco: {cidade: 'Lontras'}};
```

não obtive sucesso.

Qual a maneira certa de fazer esta ***metamorfose***, onde possuo um objeto dentro de outro?

Comment: não ficou muito claro seu problema, coloque o código todo com o resultado esperado para ficar mais fácil

Answer (score 2):

Se você for modificar apenas uma das propriedades de um objeto interno, como o `endereco`, você terá que desconstruir esse objeto interno também, do contrário você estaria apenas sobrescrevendo o objeto `endereco` com outro objeto que possui apenas a propriedade que você declarou, no caso, `cidade`. Exemplo:

```js
const usuario = {
  nome: 'Diego',
  idade: 23,
  endereco: {
    cidade: 'Rio do Sul',
    uf: 'SC',
    pais: 'Brasil',
  }
};

const usuario2 = { 
  ...usuario, 
  endereco: {
    ...usuario.endereco, 
    cidade: 'Lontras'
  }
};

console.log(usuario2);
```